# How to get a smooth circle shape on a curved cylinder mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm trying to get a smooth circular shape on a cylinder. Each time I increase the loop cuts, starting from 16 vertices, all the way to 40. The one with 40 vertices is more smooth but again not so perfect. At the same time I also don't want to increase the vertices count to begin with the cylinder having 64, so what's the correct or best method to get a better result.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why you're not glad with your solutions and also you show a variety of cylinder radius so it's not clear what is the one you're trying to achieve. But you can try this way:

First create a high resolution cylinder, like 128, scale it on Z, give it a name like "Shrink" and hide it:

[image]

Now create a 16 vertex cylinder, cut 3 horizontal loops, cut a hole, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the first cylinder as *Target*:

[image]

Select the hole edge loop and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*. The circle will stick to a cylinder shape, thanks to the modifier, apply the modifier:

[image]

Extrude, fill the faces, bevel the edges:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth:

[image]

Comment: +1 the modelling master strikes back again...

Comment: with my hammer this time

Comment: please ...please...keep your hammer in your trousers....

Comment: Thanks for this technique. I tried it, but was making some error with the shrink-wrap modifier.  My cylinders from close up have pinches on the circles which are not obvious in my image I uploaded. But now after following your method, the result is superb, always helpful!