# How to join or bridge this section

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm trying to bridge or join the section in the images provided. One pole (RED LINES) is slimmer than the other (CYAN). I tried to bridge and then scale to match the thickness where the handlebar circle mesh is, but I'm getting wrong results. What's the correct method to make the middle mesh join with both of the other meshes giving it a welded look, and keeping the middle mesh correctly scaled to join them.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by wrong results? What is the problem you have with the result you have on the  bottom screenshot?

Comment: if you notice on the bottom screen shot the bridging mesh goes from thick to thin, but it should be one thickness when joining the mesh.

Comment: @blenderbreath Well, you said in the question you tried to scale and match the thickness - when you want it to be one thickness then scale it to be one thickness and not different on both ends. Or delete the vertices on the side that's too thin, then select the others and extrude them. Usually the thickness should stay the same then. And whatever you have done to join the mesh on the thick end, you have to do on the other end as well, only adjusted to the correct thickness. A rod with a certain diameter will naturally enclose more of a thin pole than a thick pole.

Comment: why don't you just extrude the "hole" from one mesh until it is very close to the other and then bridge it?

Comment: Hello Blender Breath, actually your question is the same as this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279051/how-to-get-a-smooth-circle-shape-on-a-curved-cylinder-mesh Also, you should better work on a low-poly object with a Subdivision Surface modifier, it will simplify your work